# JQuery how to wait until element AND child nodes are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, load

I am loading an element from another HTML File with the jQuery.load() method. 
The element I am loading also has some child nodes, which I am trying to access basically right after the loading call.

Now here's the issue. At the point where I try to access the child elements via document.getElementById() they are not loaded yet, and I just get null/undefined.
 Is there any way to delay or wait until everything is loaded in properly? Or some other sort of fix? 
Thanks in advance!

**Fun addition:** element.childNodes returns a HTMLCollection with length 1, but childNodes[0] returns undefined (even though there is a value when just printing the Collection)

Comment: `jQuery.load()` expects a callback ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/)). That callback function will be executed when the loading has completed. Only then, you can do your `getElementById`

Comment: You need `$('#container').load(url, null, function () { /* do whatever here */ });`

Comment: @ChrisG exactly - I totally misread the Q

Comment: Regarding the fun addition: console output of objects is *live*, meaning it will update when the value changes.